# Error when trying to compare two Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to compare two dataframes coming from 2 databases likes this:

dif1

`    NAME      VALUE    ID

0   TMPA4     1     009450
1   TMPA7     8     009452
2   TMPA4     4     009463
3   TMPA2     6     009674
4   TMPA4     2     009456
...

dif2

0  TMPA4     1      009450

1  TMPA9     3      009674
2  TMPA4     1      009674

...`

I need to get the following:

- records on both which name + id are the same but different value

ex: 0   TMPA4     1     009450

- records (name + id) only on df1.

ex: 3   TMPA2     6     009674

- records (name + id) only on df2

ex: 1  TMPA9     3      009674

When trying to compare them with something like this I get this error : **Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
...
`dif1['diff_value'] = np.where((dif1['NAME'] == dif2['NAME']) & (dif1['ID'] == dif2['ID']) & (dif1['VALUE'] != dif2['VALUE']) , 'True', 'False')
```

Do anyone know why I'm getting this error?
Any help to get those 3 cases would be apreciated!

thanks in advance.

Comment: Needs formatting, try using "```" for your table display to make it look better.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['NAME', 'VALUE', 'ID'], how='inner')
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post